# Book recommendations on how to conduct simulations in the context of OLS and Structural Equation Modelling

Tags: regression, self-study, references, simulation, structural-equation-modeling

The title really says it all. Does anyone have any recommendations for well-written books, preferably with plenty of examples, on how to conduct simulation studies in the context of OLS and Structural Equation Modeling?

I am aware that there are some tutorials online on these topics. But I am really looking for the actual books that explain clearly how to conduct such simulation studies. Please explain why a specific book is recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about books, honestly there is not that much into it, but there are some papers that are usually recommended as references

- Mplus userguide chapter 12, https://www.statmodel.com/ugexcerpts.shtml

Although examples are in Mplus, it should be easy to apply them to lavaan

- Muthen, L. K., & Muthen, B. O. (2002). How to use a Monte Carlo study to decide on sample size and determine power. Structural equation modeling, 9(4), 599-620.

Also with Mplus code

- Wolf, E. J., Harrington, K. M., Clark, S. L., & Miller, M. W. (2013). Sample size requirements for structural equation models: An evaluation of power, bias, and solution propriety. Educational and psychological measurement, 73(6), 913-934.
- Thoemmes, F., MacKinnon, D. P., & Reiser, M. R. (2010). Power analysis for complex mediational designs using Monte Carlo methods. Structural Equation Modeling, 17(3), 510-534.

Then there is

- Beaujean, A. A. (2014). Sample size determination for regression models using Monte Carlo methods in R. Practical Assessment, Research & Evaluation, 19.

which is for regression, but kind of more approachable then the other SEM papers, thus it can be used as a stepping stone, to build your way up to the other papers. It also contains R code.

There are also other more general how to simulation papers, more aimed at evaluating new methods

- Burton, A., Altman, D. G., Royston, P., & Holder, R. L. (2006). The design of simulation studies in medical statistics. Statistics in Medicine, 25(24), 4279–4292. doi: 10.1002/sim.2673
- Morris, T. P., White, I. R., & Crowther, M. J. (2019). Using simulation studies to evaluate statistical methods. Statistics in Medicine, 38(11), 2074–2102. doi: 10.1002/sim.8086

I am sure there is more out there, but these are the most popular as far as I know.

Comment: That's generally useful, thank you. By any chance, are you aware of any other books except for the Mplus User Guide? Also, I would be very appreciative if you upvoted the question, so hopefully there is more awareness for people who want to conduct simulation studies. Thank you in advance